# Post request to third party service from node server

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

What is the best way to send POST request from node server which has received the request parameter from a client?
 Reason I am asking for best practice because it should not affect the response time if multiple clients are calling the node service.
Here is the **Backbone Model** which sends the request to node server:

```
var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'http://localhost:3000/login',

    defaults: {
        email:"",
        password:""
    },
    parse: function(resp) {
        return resp;
    },
    login: function() {
        console.log('Here in the model'+JSON.stringify(this));
        this.save();
    }
});
var loginModel = new LoginModel();
```

**Node Server**

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express');

var app = express();
    app.listen(3000);
app.post('/login', [express.urlencoded(), express.json()], function(req, res) {
    console.log('You are here'); console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    //Send the post request to third party service.
});
```

Should I use something like `requestify` inside `app.post()` function and make a call to third party service?

Answer (score 1):

I like [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) personally but [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) is very popular. [hyperquest](https://www.npmjs.org/package/hyperquest) is also worth consideration as it resolves some issues with just using the node core `http` module for this.

> Reason I am asking for best practice because it should not affect the response time if multiple clients are calling the node service.

First, just get it working. After it's working you can consider putting a cache somewhere in your stack either between your clients and your api or between your server and the third party api. I'm of the opinion that if you don't know exactly where you need a cache, exactly why, and exactly how it will benefit your application, you don't need a cache, or at the very least, you aren't prepared instrumentation-wise to understand whether your cache is helping or not.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLynos. Just to confirm, is it ok to call another service from `app.post()`.

Comment: Sure, if that makes sense for your application, of course.